# installing `libm.so.6` through Anaconda

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, libc, librosa

I have a centOS machine that I do not have sudo access.

I needed to use `librosa` python package so I have installed Anaconda and installed the package through conda.

However, when I import this package I get `ImportError: /lib64/libm.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.23' not found`.

Therefore, I attempted to resolve this issue by installing different library files including

- https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/openlibm
- https://anaconda.org/asmeurer/glibc
- https://anaconda.org/groakat/libc

Unfortunately, all of these didn't work out. Some even cause every command to segfault.

Does anyone know any other package or tricks I can try?

Thank you

Comment: Did you use  `conda install -c conda-forge librosa` to install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CentOS already comes with `libm.so.6` preinstalled, but the version is too old. It is 2.17 in CentOS 7 and 2.12 in CentOS 6. The software you are trying to use has been built for at least glibc 2.23, or later version. You will have to obtain a copy of the software built for the CentOS version you use, or build the software yourself from source.